# Rust: DateTime::parse_from_rfc3339 gives ParseError(Invalid)

Tags: rust

I am trying to get some data using Bungie API. There is last played date in json response in format like "2022-09-18T02:17:59Z". I would like to parse it and create DateTime object.

I have following code (personal data replaced by XXX):

```
const API_ROOT: &str = "https://www.bungie.net/Platform";
const API_KEY_HEADER: &str = "X-API-Key";

const MY_API_KEY: &str = "XXX";

const MEMBERSHIP_TYPE: &str = "XXX";
const MEMBERSHIP_ID: &str = "XXX";

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), reqwest::Error> {
    let url = format!("{}/Destiny2/{}/Profile/{}/?components=100", API_ROOT, MEMBERSHIP_TYPE, MEMBERSHIP_ID);

    let req = reqwest::Client::new()
        .get(url)
        .header(API_KEY_HEADER, MY_API_KEY)
        .send()
        .await?
        .text()
        .await?;

    let data: JsonValue = serde_json::from_str(&req).expect("Failed to read json from response!");

    let name = &data["Response"]["profile"]["data"]["userInfo"]["displayName"].to_string();
    println!("Name: {}", name);

    let last_played_raw = &data["Response"]["profile"]["data"]["dateLastPlayed"].to_string();
    println!("{}", last_played_raw);
    let last_played_raw = last_played_raw.replace("Z", "+00:00");
    println!("{}", last_played_raw);

    let last_played = DateTime::parse_from_rfc3339(&last_played_raw).unwrap();

    println!("Last played: {}", last_played);

    Ok(())
}
```

Problem is that parsing last_played_raw string panicks:

```
"2022-09-18T02:17:59Z"
"2022-09-18T02:17:59+00:00"
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: ParseError(Invalid)', src\main.rs:37:70
```

Can somebody please tell me, what could be wrong?

Comment: I can not reproduce the problem with your code. Is [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=afe4d85dabcad4409627721618c84e0b) what you are trying to do?

Comment: Yes. But in my case, string with datetime is not constant. I am getting it from json data.

Comment: I made minimal [example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=2b6b190a89f60f8c7bb6b4b12efa2672). It gives same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this happens is fairly simple. It happens because the leading and trailing quotation marks (`"`) are included in the string that you passed into `DateTime::parse_from_rfc3339()`. Probably the least incisive change to fix this would be to replace these with empty string literals like so:

```rust
extern crate serde_json;
extern crate serde;

use serde_json::Value as JsonValue;
use chrono::DateTime;

fn main() {
    let json_string = r#"{"dateLastPlayed": "2022-09-18T02:17:59Z"}"#;

    let data: JsonValue = serde_json::from_str(json_string).unwrap();

    let last_played = data["dateLastPlayed"].to_string().replace("\"", "");
    println!("{}", last_played.as_str());

    let datetime = DateTime::parse_from_rfc3339(last_played.as_str()).expect("Failed to parse");
    println!("{}", datetime);
}
```

Here is a link to the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=bc6aeb005aafb5a69e342191b46d9f45) where you can see this easily.

However in `serde` you typically don't work with the raw `Value` and instead handle deserializing like so:

```rust
use serde::Deserialize;
use chrono::DateTime;

#[derive(Deserialize)]
#[serde(rename_all = "camelCase")]
struct MyData {
    date_last_played: String,
}

fn main() {
    let json_string = r#"{"dateLastPlayed": "2022-09-18T02:17:59Z"}"#;

    let data: MyData = serde_json::from_str(json_string).unwrap();

    let datetime = DateTime::parse_from_rfc3339(data.date_last_played.as_str()).expect("Failed to parse");
    println!("{}", datetime);
}
```

Here is the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=9ecdd044be25068987af5cd6cf140eec) for the above.

You should also be able to directly parse the JSON using this struct

```rust
struct MyData {
    date_last_played: DateTime,
}
```

which would be the preferred choice, but you will need a custom serde [`Deserializer`](https://serde.rs/impl-deserializer.html) for this.

Comment: Removing quotation marks helped. Thanks!